# Qt Creator Error when trying to split a QString

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt6

I have a string that I am trying to split on the first instance of the delimiter, in this case "~". These are the calls I am making:

```cpp
QString line = "hello~world~how~are~you";
QStringList list = line.split("~", Qt::SplitLimit::KeepEmptyParts, Qt::CaseSensitive);
```

Ideally I would get:

```
list.at(0); = "hello"  
list.at(1); = "world~how~are~you"
```

However this throws an error.

```
.... error: 'Qt::SplitLimit' has not been declared
.... In function 'int qMain(int, char**)':
```

I am using Qt Creator version 6.4.2 with Microsoft Windows 10 and I am trying to code in C++. I am using the CMake build system. I have included QtCore in the project, so that shouldn't be the issue.

I do not know if this is the best way to split a QString so if anyone has a better suggestion I would gladly try it.
In the meantime I think I will just fully split it. Use the first entry, and then re-append the rest together.

Comment: Where have you found `SplitLimit`? Shouldn't that be `SplitBehavior`, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#SplitBehaviorFlags-enum

Comment: Yes thanks. That was the issue. I should have looked at the docs closer. Not sure if I should just delete this question. Coding late at night and your mind just starts making things up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter to `split` method is of type `Qt::SplitBehavior` and as mentioned in the comment it is an old fashioned enum not C++11 enum class.

```cpp
QStringList QString::split(const QString &sep, Qt::SplitBehavior behavior = Qt::KeepEmptyParts, Qt::CaseSensitivity cs = Qt::CaseSensitive) const
```

So you should use:

```cpp
QStringList list = line.split("~", Qt::KeepEmptyParts, Qt::CaseSensitive);
```

But, QString's split method splits the string into substrings wherever *sep* occurs, and returns the list of those strings. **You can't partially split the string using `split` method.**

To split only on the first occurrence of delimiter use `indexOf` method as follows:

```cpp
auto idx = line.indexOf('~');
auto part= line.mid(0, idx);
auto rest = line.mid(idx+1);
qDebug() << part;
qDebug() << rest;
```

Output:

```
"hello"
"world~how~are~you"
```

Comment: nothing wrong with `Qt::SplitBehavior::KeepEmptyParts` even if `SplitBehavior` isn't an `enum class` since c++11